# JuypterLab returns 404 when acessing throgh nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I setup nginx ingress-controller and run a JuypterLab pod, and try to access the JuypterLab pod through nginx ingress, it returns 404 NOT FOUND. I use `jupyter/tensorflow-notebook` image from docker hub

The JuypterLab pod is running and shows below

```
Entered start.sh with args: jupyter lab
Executing the command: jupyter lab
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.361 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2021-11-17 09:20:17.365 NotebookApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-11-17 09:20:17.365 NotebookApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-11-17 09:20:17.365 NotebookApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.375 ServerApp] Writing Jupyter server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.603 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.639 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.640 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.640 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.11.2 is running at:
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp] http://nb-notebook-sample:8888/lab?token=396d9a16b3703c41754d71ddec5500bca6f5b47380170c9b
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=396d9a16b3703c41754d71ddec5500bca6f5b47380170c9b
[I 2021-11-17 09:20:17.645 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2021-11-17 09:20:17.649 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-8-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://nb-notebook-sample:8888/lab?token=xxxxxxxx
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=xxxxxxxxxx
[I 2021-11-17 09:21:08.128 ServerApp] 302 GET / (10.240.0.35) 0.84ms
```

The ingress I used

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    labels:
      notebook.kubedl.io/notebook-name: notebook-sample
    name: nb-notebook-sample
    namespace: default
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: nb-notebook-sample
              port:
                name: nb-port
          path: /notebooks/default/nb-notebook-sample
          pathType: Prefix
```

The access url through nginx is: http://{nginx-ip}/notebooks/default/nb-notebook-sample

Lastly, it works if I use LoadBalancer service type, and access through external ip: http://{JuypterLab-pod-ip}

When accessing through External LoadBalancer, the url will automatically append `lab?` in the end.
May be this is due to the nginx-rewrite annotation ?

I tried to rewrite to `/lab`,still not working.

Comment: I had a similar situation. I set a host (a domain name), set `paths.path` as `/`, and remove the rewrite rule, then it can access via Ingress.